# Tor ExitNodes not working in the torrc?

Tags: configuration, ip-address, exit-policies

I'm new to Tor and installed it and torsocks on a fresh ubuntu machine. I've set up and configured the torrc file with the following parameters:

```
ExitNodes A0C59410B9030AC1385C4CA44C8DBFE13AF4BC9B
StrictNodes 1
```

my aim is to use an exitpoint in the UK to access UK traffic, I have previously also tried:

```
ExitNodes {gb}
StrictNodes 1
```

However, when I check what my IP is using the command:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org |& grep -Po "(?<=strong>)[\d\.]+(?=</strong)"
```

the IP address that I get back is not in the UK. it usually ends up being an IP in France or Germany. I have of course also restarted the tor service through terminal but that does not make any difference either. I was under the impression that it would try to connect to the specified endpoint or timeout otherwise. Am I missing something obvious? None of the other similar questions that have been asked about this previously are not working for me either.

I was using tor version 0.3.* but I tried upgrading to 0.4.5.8 and am still running into the same issue.

Comment: (Just a note, `StrictNodes` does not apply to `ExitNodes`.)

Comment: Well, that explains one thing at the very least.

Comment: have you solved this problem? I encounter this problem now, and don't know how to fix it